# workbench access issue "this app is blocked by Transaction Security"

Tags: error, workbench

some of my colleagues have issue with accessing to workbench. When they try to login they receive below error:

> app_blocked: this app is blocked by Transaction Security

Is it SalesForce account issue?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is something called Enhanced Transaction Security. [Here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.enhanced_transaction_security_policy_types.htm&type=5)'s the Salesforce documentation for it. I had not heard of this before your question.

I guess your admin/company prevents access to certain features for certain users.